# Playwright puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth example with Firefox not finishing

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, playwright

I have a Java code which executes a Node snippet like this, which is very simple:

```
public void executeCommand(){
    try{
        System.out.println(command);
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        //final boolean done = p.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("WAITING FOR THE COMMAND TO RESPOND. "); 
        final Stream<String>data = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())).lines().peek(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("Step--->1"); 
        final List<String>lines = data.collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Step--->2"); 
        final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(lines.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("empty response"+" in:"+(endTime-startTime)+" ms.");
        }else{                
            System.out.println("lines = " + lines.size()+" in:"+(endTime-startTime)+" ms.");
            lines.forEach(System.out::println);
            //System.out.println("lines = " + lines.size()+" in:"+(endTime-startTime)+" ms.");
        }            
    }catch(final Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The command variable is something like:

```
private final String command  = "node C:\\Users\\chipe\\Desktop\\EjemploConChrome.js";
```

And the file is something like this. Indeed this is just a resemblance of [official plugin test code](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/playwright-extra#-puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth):

```
// playwright-extra is a drop-in replacement for playwright,
// it augments the installed playwright with plugin functionality
const { chromium } = require('playwright-extra')

// Load the stealth plugin and use defaults (all tricks to hide playwright usage)
// Note: playwright-extra is compatible with most puppeteer-extra plugins
const stealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')()

// Add the plugin to playwright (any number of plugins can be added)
chromium.use(stealth)

// That's it, the rest is playwright usage as normal 
chromium.launch({ headless: false }).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  console.log('Testing the stealth plugin..')
  await page.goto('https://bot.sannysoft.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' })
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'stealth.png', fullPage: true })

  console.log('All done, check the screenshot. ✨')
  await browser.close()
})
```

When I executed it works correctly:

[image: Running Code using Chromium]

But when I execute the Firefox version of it just replacing `chromium` with `firefox`:

```
// playwright-extra is a drop-in replacement for playwright,
// it augments the installed playwright with plugin functionality
const { firefox } = require('playwright-extra')

// Load the stealth plugin and use defaults (all tricks to hide playwright usage)
// Note: playwright-extra is compatible with most puppeteer-extra plugins
const stealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')()

// Add the plugin to playwright (any number of plugins can be added)
firefox.use(stealth)

// That's it, the rest is playwright usage as normal 
firefox.launch({ headless: false }).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  console.log('Testing the stealth plugin..')
  await page.goto('https://bot.sannysoft.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'stealth.png', fullPage: true })
  console.log('All done, check the screenshot. ✨')
  await browser.close()
})
```

I can see the launching of 2 browsers instead of 1, but I don't know why.

But the execution never finish! But if I execute the command directly on command line it finish, but I need it in Java.

The browser keeps open and in this line.

```
await page.goto('https://bot.sannysoft.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });
```

And the network is idle.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Running process]

[image: Launches two browsers]

Shutting down process manually:

[image: Shutting down process]

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.